# Calculate the number of hidden tags in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have tags inside a parent with specific height and an overflow hidden. I want to calculate the number if the hidden tags.

I've tried this approach but the the result is wrong and even show a negative number.
How to calculate the correct number of the hidden tags and show them in an other element

THE HTML bloc:

```
 <div id="projectEndUserBloc">
    <div class="project-detail-market-subtitle">
        <img class="project-detail-market-img" alt="Author picture" src="/wp-content/themes/engiedigital/img/smp/logo-people.svg" />
        <label class="subtitle-project">End users</label>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
        <div id="projectEndUserContent" class="project-detail-tag-container" style="height: 92px; overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">hzeljahef</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">ef</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">fae</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">azfeafz</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">efaz</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">ezfa</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">feza</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">fazfe</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">zfz</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">feef</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">zeaf</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">faz</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">fef</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">aze</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">zaef</span></div>
            <div class="nj-tag light-blue-tag"><span class="nj-tag__text">fez</span></div>
        </div>
        <span class="count-hidden" style="display: none;">+-1</span>
        <span class="show-less-tag d-flex" style="display: none;">Show less</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

THE CODE:

```
$('#projectEndUserContent').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    var nb_all = $('#projectEndUserContent .nj-tag.light-blue-tag').length;
    var hidden_children = 0;
    var parent = document.getElementById('projectEndUserContent');
    var showing_children = 1;
    [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#projectEndUserContent .light-blue-tag')).forEach(function(child) {
        if (isVisible(parent, child) == true) {
            showing_children += 1;
        };
    });

    function isVisible(parent, child) {
        return !(
            (child.offsetLeft - parent.offsetLeft > parent.offsetWidth) ||
            (child.offsetTop - parent.offsetLeft > parent.offsetHeight)
        )
    }
    hidden_children = nb_all - showing_children;
    if (hidden_children != 0) {
        $('#projectEndUserBloc .count-hidden').toggleClass('d-flex')
    }
    $('#projectEndUserBloc .count-hidden').text('+' + hidden_children);
    $('#projectEndUserBloc .count-hidden').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().children('#projectEndUserContent').css({
            'height': 'max-content',
            'overflow': 'visible'
        });
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $(this).parent().children('.show-less-tag').toggleClass('d-flex');
    });
    $('#projectEndUserBloc .show-less-tag').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().children('#projectEndUserContent').css({
            'height': '92px',
            'overflow': 'hidden'
        });
        $(this).css('display', 'none');
        $('#projectEndUserBloc .count-hidden').toggleClass('d-flex');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood everything you wanted to accomplish with this code, but by quick-reading the code, this seems to be a mistake:

```
function isVisible(parent, child) {
    return !(
        (child.offsetLeft - parent.offsetLeft > parent.offsetWidth) ||
        (child.offsetTop - parent.offsetLeft > parent.offsetHeight)
    )
}
```

I think it should be:

```
function isVisible(parent, child) {
    return !(
        (child.offsetLeft - parent.offsetLeft > parent.offsetWidth) ||
        (child.offsetTop - parent.offsetTop > parent.offsetHeight)
    )
}
```

Comment: i have a list of tags and i want to show at the first time only two rows of tags and hide the others. Count the hidden tags and show the total in a toggle button ( like show more / show less )